# Is there a way to lock date time to only allow selection of the last 12 months

Tags: html, datepicker

So I have a input field that allows a user to select a date.

```
<input type="date" data-date-format="DD MMMM YYYY" name="start_date">
```

Is there a way to lock it so that only a date within the last year from the current date is selected ?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968781/jquery-datepicker-selecting-the-last-day-of-the-month?rq=1

Comment: thanks, il check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `min` and `max` attributes for this.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html

Answer (score 0):

you can set the **min** and **max** values of your input. To do it programmatically, since your requirement is 1 year before current date, change the attributes on first load for example using **jQuery**.

`var currentdate = new Date();
$('#start_date').attr('min', currentdate.setFullYear(currentdate.getYear()-1));
$('#start_date').attr('max', currentdate);`